# Frostbite Spider caves/lairs

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Just wondering if anyone has found a cave with a lot of Frostbite spiders in it they seem to be the best way to get petty soul gems atm i have found Crovangr Cave are there any others?

Comment: You're getting soul gems from spiders?  I got soul gems from dwarven ruins.  Easy to fill them from druegr tombs.

Comment: well filling empty soul gems with there souls....the dwarven ruin idea is interesting though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volskygge has a tunnel with a good number of frostbite spiders in it. However, it is also on a one-way road to a nasty draugr boss. If you feel up to taking him on, you get an excellent item out of it, Volsung's Mask. But save your game when you get to the puzzle room because solving the puzzle commits you to going forward. That way if the draugr at the end is too difficult you can just leave and find some spiders that are less hassle.

Comment: ahh lol dragon preist are easy to kill :p ty for the cave suggestion i will take a look at it =)

Answer (score 1):

I recently finished the totems mission for the companions and one of the locations was full of spiders.

Cronvangr Cave

Comment: He says in his question that he found this cave